# find if each row of a logical matrix has at least one TRUE

Tags: r, matrix

is there some way to convert this data:

```
        (Intercept) Timecoursecdc15 Timecoursecdc28 Timecourseclb Timecoursecln
YAL001C       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL002W       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL003W       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL004W       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL005C       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL007C       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE          TRUE
```

to something like this:

```
  YPR163C   YPR164W   YPR165W   YPR166C   YPR167C   YPR168W   YPR169W   YPR170C 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
  YPR171W   YPR172W   YPR173C   YPR174C   YPR175W   YPR176C   YPR177C   YPR178W 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
  YPR179C   YPR180W   YPR181C   YPR182W   YPR183W   YPR184W   YPR185W   YPR186C 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
  YPR187W   YPR188C   YPR189W   YPR190C   YPR191W   YPR192W   YPR193C   YPR194C 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
  YPR195C   YPR196W   YPR197C   YPR198W   YPR199C   YPR200C   YPR201W   YPR202W 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
```

So, looking at the values of each row, if any row contains TRUE, then `YAL007C` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible? In your sample you don't have values you expect in the result (like YPR163C).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
apply(df, 1, any)
# YAL001C YAL002W YAL003W YAL004W YAL005C YAL007C 
#   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE
```

Comment: Sadly, loses the speed contest.  However, this approach could be useful in finding nonlogical values, e.g.  `x<-sample(1:10,10,rep=TRUE); apply(x,7,any)`

Comment: @Carl, not sure what you mean by your example: `x` is a vector and all methods will error out because of it.

Comment: @flodel well, aside from not thinking at all :-), should have been `x<-matrix(sample(1:30,16,rep=TRUE),4,4); apply(x,1,function(j) any(j%in%7))`

Comment: well, then you can do `rowSums(matrix(x %in% 7, 4, 4)) > 0L` or `rowSums(x == 7) > 0`.

Answer (score 20):

Like this:

```
rowSums(dat) > 0L
```

which will be a lot faster than using a loop or apply...

Comment: +1 This is the fastest approach for large data frames!

Comment: *caveat emptor*: this does not work with missing values. `any(c(NA, TRUE))` results in `TRUE` but `sum(c(NA, TRUE))>0L` results in `NA`. Adding the argument `na.rm=T` to `rowSums` will solve the dilemma. However, the reverse problem happens when evaluating whether *all* rows are `TRUE`: a missing value *should* result in an `NA` in that case. `any` and `all` handle both conditions appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

If your data is in a data frame, this is a fast approach:

```
setNames(Reduce("|", dat), rownames(dat))
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

If you have a matrix, you can use this:

```
setNames(Reduce("|", as.data.frame(mat)), rownames(dat))
```

where `mat` is the name of your matrix.

The latter command works with both matrices and data frames.

---

Performance check (based on the example data in the question):

```
testDF <- read.table(text = "(Intercept) Timecoursecdc15 Timecoursecdc28 Timecourseclb Timecoursecln
YAL001C       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL002W       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL003W       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL004W       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL005C       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE         FALSE
YAL007C       FALSE           FALSE           FALSE         FALSE          TRUE",
                 check.names = FALSE)

applyFun <- function() apply(testDF, 1, any)
rowSumsFun <- function() rowSums(testDF) > 0L
ReduceFun <- function() setNames(Reduce("|", testDF), rownames(testDF))

library(microbenchmark)

Unit: microseconds
         expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
   applyFun() 234.444 237.6535 239.7680 250.0900 823.751   100
 rowSumsFun() 153.645 155.8345 157.1610 159.5245 387.071   100
  ReduceFun()  55.588  57.9465  60.1465  61.9545 370.339   100



# create data frame with 10000 times as many rows as the original one
testDF <- do.call(rbind, replicate(10000, testDF, simplify = FALSE))

microbenchmark(applyFun(), rowSumsFun(), ReduceFun())
Unit: milliseconds
         expr        min         lq    median        uq       max neval
   applyFun() 337.457512 395.721527 429.13247 474.37774 698.43850   100
 rowSumsFun()   5.591884   7.765213   9.17471  10.21152  16.93731   100
  ReduceFun()   9.900725  11.418231  12.95423  13.32382  16.20043   100
```

Summary: For a small number of rows, the approach based on `Reduce` is the most efficient one, but the approach based on `rowSums` is the best for large data frames. I would prefer using the `rowSums` solution for the general case.

Comment: `as.data.frame` on a data.frame is very fast, so you can just make the last one the most general one. Call the input `dat`.

Comment: @flodel I agree that using `as.data.frame` qualifies for a general solution, but I want to keep the more efficient version too.

Comment: Well then +1 for almost assembler like R solution :)