# Logical vector across many columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to run a logical or statement across many columns in data.table but I am having trouble coming up with the code. My columns have a pattern like the one shown in the table below. I could use a regular logical vector if needed, but I was wondering if I could figure out a way to iterate across a1, a2, a3, etc. as my actual dataset has many "a" type columns.

Thanks in advance.

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(a1 = c(1, 4, 5, 6), a2 = c(2, 4, 1, 10), z = c(9, 10, 12, 12))

# this works but does not work for lots of a1, a2, a3 colnames 
# because code is too long and unwieldy
x[a1 == 1 | a2 == 1 , b:= 1] 

# this is broken and returns the following error
x[colnames(x)[grep("a", names(x))] == 1, b := 1]
```

```
Error in `[.data.table`(x, colnames(x)[grep("a", names(x))] == 1, `:=`(b,  : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 2 but there are 4 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.
```

Output looks like below:

```
   a1 a2  z  b
1:  1  2  9  1
2:  4  4 10 NA
3:  5  1 12  1
4:  6 10 12 NA
```

Comment: When I try `x[a1 == 1 | a2 == 1 , b:= 1]` I get no output at all. What would your desired result look like?

Comment: I edited the above to add the output. If you rerun x, you will get the above output.

Comment: `x[, v := Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(.SD, \`==\`, 1)), .SDcols=a1:a2]` works for the example. You could read the docs for how to specify `.SDcols` in other ways. Generally, rowwise calculations on a data.table/data.frame will not be efficient. Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/21498467 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26740297

Answer (score 1):

Try using a mask:

```
x$b <- 0
x[rowSums(ifelse(x[, list(a1, a2)] == 1, 1, 0)) > 0, b := 1]
```

Now imagine you have 100 `a` columns and they are the first 100 columns in your data table. Then you can select the columns using:

```
x[rowSums(ifelse(x[, c(1:100)] == 1, 1, 0) > 0, b := 1]
```

`ifelse(x[, list(a1, a2)] == 1, 1, 0)` returns a data table that only has the values `1` where there is a `1` in the `a` columns. Then I used rowSums to sum horizontally, and if any of these sums is `> 0`, it means there was a `1` in at least one of the columns of a given row, so I simply selected those rows and set `b` to `1`.